# Difference between point matrix and coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been learning recently about coordinate vectors and point matrices and how they are inverses of each other. That is, $$C_b = P_b^{-1}$$ Similarly I came across a few relations between coordinate, vectors and matrices wherein 
$$C_b \times X = X^{'}$$
$$P_b \times X^{'} = X$$

where X is a point and X' is a vector. However, I am unclear about their definitions exactly. So far I have been thinking of coordinates and points as the same thing. What exactly is the difference in this context? I tried finding more information online but I couldn't. Could anyone please break it down for me.

Comment: What is a point matrix?

Comment: So far, all i know is that it is the inverse of the coordinate vector. So multiplying that with a coordinate yields a point.

Comment: It appears that point matrix is basically a matrix containing the basis vectors as columns.